# PHP file upload script doesn't work on my server but works on different server

Tags: php

This is the script I am testing on my server which says file upload failed.
But when I try on different server it works. Does any one know is this something to do with my php.ini setting or...

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="fupload.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="512000" />
    Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>

<?php

$uploaddir = '/var/www/vhosts/costsave.net.au/httpdocs/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo "<p>";

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
  echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
   echo "Upload failed";
}

echo "</p>";
echo '<pre>';
echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);
print "</pre>";

?>
```

**Error**

[image]

Comment: Most likely a permissions issue. Do you have errors set to display?

Comment: The most common problem is lack of `write` rights to the folder. Get that thing off the list first.

Comment: Some hoster forbid move_uploaded_file()

Comment: Error image updated there

Comment: Just the wired thing is, this script works on other web server

Comment: Value: 7; Failed to write file to disk. Introduced in PHP 5.1.0. Your permissions to the folder is not right

Comment: Permission is fine has 777

Comment: Live url is here: http://costsave.net.au/admin/fupload.php

Comment: Is the permission also correct for the temp upload directory? **upload_tmp_dir** string in php.ini. The temporary directory used for storing files when doing file upload. Must be writable by whatever user PHP is running as. If not specified PHP will use the system's default.

If the directory specified here is not writable, PHP falls back to the system default temporary directory. If open_basedir is on, then the system default directory must be allowed for an upload to succeed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My server tmp folder was full that's why it was refusing to create tmp file.

Comment: @Dips Np, Added it to my earlier answer so you can close the question

Answer (score 2):

Settings related to file uploads:

- file_uploads
- upload_max_filesize
- upload_tmp_dir
- post_max_size
- max_input_time

Ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

> **file_uploads** boolean or integer
>
> Whether or not to allow HTTP file uploads.

Is the permission also correct for the temp upload directory?

> **upload_tmp_dir** string
>
> The temporary directory used for
>   storing files when doing file upload. Must be writable by whatever
>   user PHP is running as. If not specified PHP will use the system's
>   default. If the directory specified here is not writable, PHP falls
>   back to the system default temporary directory. If open_basedir is on,
>   then the system default directory must be allowed for an upload to
>   succeed

Answer (score 1):

Please check if CHMOD is set for `/var/www/vhosts/costsave.net.au/httpdocs/uploads/` and has writing privileges.

As another option you can output `$_FILES['userfile']['error']` to see what happens.

Comment: Your live url now has another Parse Error ;)

Comment: I found the problem now. My server tmp folder is full that's reason it can't create tmp file.